# Binding to NSComboBox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

I am very new to Cocoa and I am developing one normal Cocoa desktop application in Xcode 4.5. I have a requirement to display values in `NSComboBox` and I have to retrieve from `NSComboBox`, but restriction is that I should not do bindings to `IBOutlet`.

If we want we need any use of Array controllers we can use `NSArrayController`s but not with `IBOutlet`s.

Will any one suggest me how to perform this task without using `IBOutlet`s.

I don't want to use `IBOutlet`s because of:

1. It reduces the code: Assume we have 15 text fields in UI, so you need to have 15
   `IBOutlet`s (If you are working on small project you can have it but
   when we implement bigger size project, you may end up creating tons
   of `IBOutlet`s, which does nothing other then helping to access
   value from the text fields.

   If you use binding rather than `IBOutlet`, handling UI is easy, Let's assume you have one         table with linked arrayController. When array is modified which you linked with array Controller, automatically changes will reflect in the tableView, you no need bother about updating the tabelView, if we use `IBOutlet`, we have to scratch out head to update the content. Whenever data is modified which we display in tableView.
2. Makes developer's life easy: If we use bindings, Any changes happened in binding object immediately reflects in the UI, we need not worry about updating of UI.
3. Easy-to-understand code: If we use `IBOutlet`s unnecessarily we end up with writing code to handle views, updating views and etc, in case we use bindings automatically it updates.

According to me. Good practice if we use bindings.

`IBOutlet`s simply increase length of code.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: where to retrieve the value in a textfield?

Answer (score 1):

Steps how to bind:

1. Draw a NSComboBox and a NSTextField that would be bind to combo box.
2. In combo box add items from Interface Builder.
3. Select Combo box. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag to NStextField/label and select 
   `takeStringValueFrom`.

That's it!!!

Now you can build & run and check the selection changes in combo box is visible in textfield as well.

Comment: But to do these we have to hide that label or textfield from the user to display, isn't there any other way to get solution for my problem?

Comment: My requirement is, I have 2 combo boxes. Based on the first combo box values the second combo's values should get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up your combo boxes delegate to handle comboBoxSelectionDidChange method.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/221619-detecting-when-nscombobox-text-changed-by-list.html